# find exactly one file in directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find

I have very big collection of files.
When I use command find I'm sure there is only one file in this collection. 
To make all my find commands faster I would like to run find command just until it had found one file. I don't need to wait for more files.
Maybe some bash script with breaks....

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With GNU `find` you can use the `-quit` option.

For example, the following command will print the first txt file found and then exit.

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print -quit
```

Comment: Thx. It worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the manual (`man find`):

> -quit
>
> Exit immediately.  No child processes will be left running,
>   but no more paths specified on the
>             command  line  will be processed.  For example, find /tmp/foo /tmp/bar -print -quit will print
>             only /tmp/foo.  Any command lines which have been built up with -execdir  ...  {}  +  will  be
>             invoked  before  find exits.   The exit status may or may not be zero, depending on whether an
>             error has already occurred.

Answer (score 0):

you could use find with sed:

```
[za@pc-02 ~]$ find ./ -iname  '[0-9]' | sed 1q
./1
[za@pc-02 ~]$ find ./ -iname  '[0-9]'
./1
./3
./2
[za@apc-02 ~]$ ls
1  2  3  vim
```

**sed 1q** - means that you need only one line which produces by find
if you need more than one line write this `10q`(10 lines)

**[0-9]** this regexp means match only one digit in range `0-9`

Comment: this answer is not very helpful as is. maybe you can say at least few words to explain what do you really mean and how does it answer the question?

Comment: updated with short explanation